# How to extract <img> src from an <a> tag with a certain class?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to get this to work for a while but can't figure it out. There is an `<a>` tag inside a `<div>`. Inside the `<a>` tag is an `<img>` This is what the html looks like:

```
<div class="preview">
    <a class="zoom" href="#"><img src="theimage.jpg" alt="drink"></a>
</div>
```

My BeautifulSoup code:

```
divdata = soup2.findAll('div', {"class": "preview"})
for getatag in divdata.find('a', {'class': 'zoom'}):
    for getimgtag in getatag.findAll('img',src=True):
        print getimgtag['src']
```

Comment: `find()` doesn't return a list, you shouldn't use `for-in` to process it.

Comment: Or you could change the second line to use `findAll` if there can be more than one `a` in the `div`.

Comment: I tried `findAll` but i am getting this error `AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'findAll'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing yourself by sometimes calling `.find()` and sometimes `.findAll()`. You are further confusing yourself by sometimes using `for x in y` and sometimes `x = y`.

Use the `for X in findAll()` pattern exclusively:

```
for divdata in soup2.findAll('div', {"class": "preview"}):
    for getatag in divdata.findAll('a', {'class': 'zoom'}):
        for getimgtag in getatag.findAll('img',src=True):
            print getimgtag['src']
```

Comment: You're right, I was really confusing myself! This seems easier to understand. I tried the above code and it doesn't print anything. However I see the `<div>` and the rest of the html in the page source. Could it be that it is generated via javascript and that is why it doesn't work?

Comment: If you see it in the page source (as in Chrome's "View Page Source" menu item), it isn't being generated by Javascript. On the other hand, if you see it in the DOM (as in Chrome's "Inspect" menu item), it might be. Can you share the URL that you are using?

Comment: Thanks, I managed to come up with a different way of scraping that data (not using python). I have so much to learn! I take it that your answer DOES answer the question with regards to code but not specific to my case so I shall mark yours as the answer. I appreciate the help Rob, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
divdata = soup2.findAll('div', {"class": "preview"})

for div in divdata:
    print(div.img.get('src'))
```

If you get the `div` tag, `.img` will get the next `img` in `div` tag's decendents.